# Need to add conditions to query

Tags: soql

I want to get parent records where the child record has conditions. I am having trouble adding child condition because I have used `WHERE` already in my SOQL statement

```
SELECT Parent__r.Id, Parent__r.Name, enrtcr__Client__r.name 
  FROM Child__c  
WHERE Parent__r.enrtcr__Site__c != null AND Parent__r.enrtcr__Rate_Type__c LIKE '%MHD - RACF%'
```

The above is working well but I wish to add `WHERE` to the child. Looking for something like this

```
SELECT Parent__r.Id, Parent__r.Name, enrtcr__Client__r.name 
  FROM Child__c  WHERE conditions XYZ AND Conditions 123
WHERE Parent__r.enrtcr__Site__c != null AND Parent__r.enrtcr__Rate_Type__c LIKE '%MHD - RACF%'
```

Comment: Can you not just put an `AND` at the end of your original `WHERE` then tack on `Child__c.Field1 = 'this' AND Child__c.Field2 != 'that'`?

Comment: What @Moonpie said.  You can lump them all into the same WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Made a comment on your post already but I thought I'd clarify - @Moonpie is correct - you put them all in the same WHERE clause, like this:

```
SELECT Parent__r.Id, Parent__r.Name, enrtcr__Client__r.name 
FROM Child__c  
WHERE Parent__r.enrtcr__Site__c != null AND Parent__r.enrtcr__Rate_Type__c LIKE '%MHD - RACF%' 
AND Child__c.Field1__c = 'value1' AND Child__c.Field2__c = 'value2'
```

You're working with the base object Child__c throughout, you just happen to be working with the fields of the parent on that object as well.